# Как сделать ограничение на количество запросов на хостинг

Tags: хостинг

В общем,надо через .htaccess сделать так,что бы с 1 IP можно было отправлять только 50 запросов на хостинг в день.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/131364/apache-limit-the-number-of-requests-traffic-per-ip

Comment: Через php - да, а насчет счетчика в htaccess как-то не слышал, пока что.

Comment: тогда как через php?